# Thread doesn't stop after join()

Tags: python, multithreading

I have this code

```
import threading

def a0():
    import a00
def a1():
    import a10
t0 = threading.Thread(target=a0)
t1 = threading.Thread(target=a1)
t0.start()
t1.start()
t0.join()
t1.join()
# some code
```

But the program doesn't run #somecode. 
However, when my code is like

```
import threading

def a0():
    import a00
def a1():
    import a10
t0 = threading.Thread(target=a0)
t1 = threading.Thread(target=a1)
t0.start()
t1.start()
# some code
```

My program is running, but t0  and t1 is not finished yet. How I can solve this?

Comment: it could happen if the importing of a00 causes an infinite loop, or any other long task

Comment: `join` waits for a thread to complete.  What is the module `a00` doing?

Comment: @cdarke a00 is not an infinite loop. I edited my post too

Comment: You need to provide a MCVE. See [_How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example_](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: `a00` might not be infinite, but it is preventing the `join` from completing.  Of course your second set of code "works":  you are exiting the program before the threads are complete.  I tried exactly your code with a dummy `a00` and it worked fine.